# Whats the future of Silverlight on the PC after v5? Is there a future?

Tags: silverlight

I have been hearing and reading lots of rumours around Silverlight 5 being the last release of Silverlight for the PC. Is this true? Is it just rumour?

Answer (score 0):

Its a rumor until Microsoft announces it! :)  And no announcements has been made on that.

So start by waiting for the official Silverlight 5 release.  After that, we will see if Microsoft still pushes for Silverlight on PCs.

Indeed its not reassuring to see that the Plug-ins are not supported in Windows 8 Metro mode.  But Silverlight will stay for sure (at least for mobiles) since its the main development platform of Windows Phone 7.  They just cant abandon it.

Comment: Well Silverlight is at the moment the core of windows phone but doesn't mean it will be in the future. :) http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/could-and-should-microsoft-change-the-heart-of-windows-phone/11164

Comment: WP7 has more than 35K applications developed using Silverlight or XNA, and the success/failure of WP7 is directly related to the amount and quality of the applications they offer.  So I don't believe that they could change the core of WP7 development just like that; frustrating (and probably loosing) all their developers.

Comment: “Switching to the NT kernel should have no impact on existing WP7 applications as those apps have no direct access to Windows CE.  This really should be a very seamless move for both applications and end-users.  The ODMs (original design manufacturers) and carriers are really the only ones who have significant work to do since drivers or any other native mode software they wrote will need to be ported or rewritten. But things written with Silverlight/.NET/XNA should just work...”

Comment: On foot note, although MS have said there is 10 years more on Silverlight if you look at Windows 8 and Metro UI. When you launch your browser within Metro it will NOT run any plugins - which includes Silverlight.